# WebdriverIO: what is the equivalent of elementIdHtml?

Tags: webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

How do I get an element's inner HTML from an `elementId` using browser object?

Is there something like `elementIdHtml` available in the WebdriverIO API?

The [getHTML](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/property/getHTML.html) link for **v4** is returning **403 Forbidden**.

---

my goal is that i need to get all text inside all `a._3cnp` from an elementId

example html

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="_3cnp">first link</a>
    <a class="_3cnp">second link</a>
    <a class="_3cnp">third link</a>
</div>
```

need to convert that to ["first link", "second link", ..]

i have the `.container` elementId already

this is what i did

```
.then(() => browser.elementIdElements(someElementId, 'a._3cnp'))
.then(buttonElem => {
    console.log('->', buttonElem)
    console.log('-->', buttonElem.getHTML)
    buttonElem.getHTML().then(x => console.log('---->', x))
    return buttonElem.value
})
```

result of elementIdElements is
buttonElem

```
{ sessionId: '2e2f144c8895a03da1b8df92f4613a33',
  status: 0,
  value:
   [ { ELEMENT: '0.6603119466268468-24',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.6603119466268468-24' } ],
  selector: 'a._3cnp' }
```

but `buttonElem.getHTML` is `undefined`

im using webdriverio standalone from botium-webdriverio-connector

Answer (score 1):

**LE:**

Change your code accordingly to the following:

```
.then(() => browser.elementIdElements(someElementId, 'a._3cnp'))
.then(buttonElem => {
    // buttonElem's 'value' will contain a list of all the matching elements
    // thus, you have to call getHTML() on each item from 'value'

    // the following will return the HTML of the first matching element
    console.log('\nPrint element HTML: ' + buttonElem.value[0].getHTML());
    return buttonElem.value[0].getHTML();
})
```

A better approach would be to loop between them & print the HTML:

```
.then(() => browser.elementIdElements(someElementId, 'a._3cnp'))
.value.forEach(buttonElem => {

    console.log('\nPrint element HTML: ' + buttonElem.getHTML());
    return buttonElem.getHTML();
})
```

---

The `.getHTML()` property is scoped to all the `ELEMENT` objects. For the sake of more didactical approach, I'm going to consider the task to be *manipulating the HTML code* found in a series of list items (`<li>`), from am unordered list (`<ul>`).

So you can do the following:

- `browser.getHTML('ul.ourList li.ourListItems')` (*this will return a list of all the `<li>`'s HTML code*)
- `browser.element('ul.ourList li.ourListItems').getHTML()` (*this will return the first `<li>'s` HTML code*)
- `$('ul.ourList li.ourListItems').getHTML()` (*this is the equivalent of the command above, only a relaxed version*)

---

If you need to iterate through all the `<li>`s & get the HTML, do this:

```
let locator = 'ul.ourList li.ourListItems';

browser.elements(locator).value.forEach(elem => {
  let elemHTML = elem.getHTML();

  console.log( JSON.stringify(elemHTML) );
  elemHTML.doSomethingWithIt();
})
```

where, `elem` will is an object with the following format:

```
{ ELEMENT: '0.285350058261731-1',
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.285350058261731-1',
  selector: 'ul li.fw-item.fz-16.lh-36.pos-r',
  value: { ELEMENT: '0.285350058261731-1' },
  index: 0 
}
```

Comment: i cant seem to make it work, i updated my question to give you more info. im using standalone version i think.

Comment: no, cannot do $('div.container'), the .container is added dynamically, so a lot of .container will actually exists, the elementId is passed to me in realtime, as "here, the newest .container, do as you will", problem is i dont know what api to use.

Comment: @lamdanchiv ya, i know i need to call ```.getHTML()```, the issue is ( as i put in the edited question above ) is that browser.elementIdElements return a json, or as your doc said "A list of WebElement JSON objects for the located elements." and there is no ```getHTML``` function inside it, therefore i cannot call ```getHTML()```, please see the edited question above.

Comment: @lamdanchiv ```browser.element('div._3058').then(elem => elem.getHTML()).then(console.log)``` throw error ```TypeError: elem.getHTML is not a function```

Comment: ah, yes, forgot to inform you, sorry. turns out it is very simple, but since cannot find documentation about standalone mode, it got quite hard. the way to get html is indeed ```$(selector).getHTML()```. But if running in standalone mode, need to chain it directly, don't call ```then()``` first. so it should be like this ```browser.elementIdElements(elementId, selector).getHTML().then(html => console.log('HTML', html))```